# Is setInterval handler considered a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

The javascript code:

```
function blah()
{
    var blahInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
        if( some_global_variable == 5 )
            clearInterval(blahInterval);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I have this code with multiple variants, and it is going to be called gazillion times in a NodeJS script. Shall I `delete blahInterval;` after `clearInterval`?

Is this a memory leak? Or the GC will clean it once setInerval function goes out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GC should clean it when it goes out of scope. As long as the if condition can be false to clear the interval. I would not consider it a memory leak.

Comment: the global variable is changed with some external event, so this setInterval handler might be executed one time or hundred times! So the question is "when does `blahInterval` goes out of scope?"

Comment: There is a local `blahInterval` created with each function call of `blah()`. So each one will go out of scope around the same time considering the if statements as the same. If `blahInterval` was a global variable we would have problems, because there would be intervals that can't be cleared when it's overwritten. Since it's local we don't have that problem.